How do you fire one particle per iteration? What is the function?
I want to know which line of Python Blender api code is responsible for creating each new particle. The Python console, which writes in Python about each Blender operation, does not write which Blender api function is executed when a particle is created, but it does write which function creates the particle system; bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add().
I want to know which Python function creates only one particle, so that I can call one particle each time to control the particle flow manually through the Blender API scripts, so that I call this function and the particle system releases one called particle.
After all, the standard particle flow is chaotic like rain, and it is impossible to specify when a particle will be released. I want to make an addon that will release a particle on call through the Python code, but I do not know what function is responsible for this.
I am a newbie but I want to make an addon in which the object will fly out one particle on a keyframe, driver, etc. within the particle system that-that this one particle works according to the set parameters of the particle system. Let’s say the particle is a projectile from the muzzle of a weapon and this particle will fly out after its call (not to be a chaotic rain as in conventional particle systems).
Question, how to use the code to call only one particle?
And, additionally, optional. Does anyone know the principle of implementation so that particles can be given a rate of fire per minute?
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

Hi. I don't think people her are gonna have an easy time interpreting what you want to achieve. Could you explain a bit better what you want, maybe add a few refence images of what you want to achieve or a GIF

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Idk how to explain it well. Roughly speaking, I want to know which line of python blender api code is responsible for creating each new particle. The python console, which writes in python about each blender operation, does not write which blender api function is executed when a particle is created, but it does write which function creates the particle system; bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add(). I want to know which python function creates only one particle, so that I can call one particle each time to control the particle flow manually through the blender api scripts.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos so that I call this function and the particle system releases one called particle. After all, the standard particle flow is chaotic like rain, and it is impossible to specify when a particle will be released. I want to make an addon that will release a particle on call through the python code, but I do not know what function is responsible for this.

Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment. Could you edit your post and include these details from comments?

Trying to make an addon when you are new to Blender in general is probably a bad idea.
